# Overriding function with enum/int

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-construction, enums

If there was a base class DeriveMe that had a function `virtual void DoSomething(int)` and a class that inherits DeriveMe called DerivedThat that had a function `void DoSomething(SomeEnum)`...would the DerivedThat override the base class DoSomething because enums evaluate to ints during compile time in C++?

I could try this by making DoSomething pure virtual and compile/run it to see if it works but this is my first stackoverflow question so I'd rather just ask it.

Comment: You know code is much clearer than an english description!

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't think the question warranted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `DerivedThat` will *hide* the function from the base class, since the signatures don't match. `enum`s do *not* evaluate to `int`, as they are a *distinct type*.

See the C++ FAQ, sections [23.9](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) and [29.19](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.19).